# Решить задача по мат анализу

Tags: математика, физика, интегральное-исчисление

Какую работу нужно произвести, чтобы насыпать кучу песка в форме полусферы радиуса R = 1.2м. Удельная плотность песка p = 1300 кг/м^3.
Я посчитал объём сферы V = (2/3)*pi*R^3 = (144/125)*pi

Масса m = V*p = (144/125)*pi*1300 = (7488/5) * pi

Дальше мои догадки:

Работа вычисляется по формуле A = mgh, отсюда вывод что h надо найти, это связано как-то с интегралами. Помогите решить, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А вы заметили, что это сайт для программистов?

Answer (score 4):

Только потому, что тут уже дали неверный ответ, и я "не могу молчать!" :)
Хотя вопрос — явный оффтопик.

По сути, надо посчитать потенциальную энергию всей кучи, т.е. проинтегрировать это самое mgh по высоте, с учетом того, что чем выше — тем меньше масса "блина".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: коварно ускользнуло же

Comment: @MBo Точно. Вот мерзопакостное...

Comment: @Harry разве там не будет просто r^2 - z^2, без корня?

Comment: Вот видите, вы уже разобрались :) Да, конечно, дико спешил, ошибся...

Comment: @Harry спасибо вам большое

Comment: Спасибо здесь принимает вид щелчка по треугольнику вверх слева от вопроса, большое спасибо — по "птичке". Если бы вы потрудились прочесть хотя бы вводную страницу сайта...